# posting.done is not a function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run the following code I get told, that posting.done is not a function. Got no clue why. I even refer to the latest version of jquery in my head. Basically what I'm trying to do is make a response message pop up when someone puts in their email address in the sidebar tab where the text field is located.

Instead I get:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: posting.done is not a function"
```

My code is below:

```
$("#newsletter").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = $("#newsletter").serialize();

    var posting = $.post("<?= PROJECT_URL?>newsletter-response", formData);

    console.dir(posting);

    posting.done(function (data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        if (response.done == 'yes') {
            $('#newsletter').fadeOut(500);
            response = "<h4>Thank you for registering.</h4>";
        } else {
            $('#newsletter').fadeOut(500);
            response = "<h4>Not successful</h4>";
        }
        $("#response").empty().append(response);
    });
    console.dir(posting.done);
});
```

Comment: What is the output of `console.dir(posting);` ?

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: He said he's using the latest version. I assume "in my head" means in `<head>`, not in his brain.

Comment: Any other errors reported in the console?

Comment: Yeah Barmar, I meant to say in my head tag (<head>).

Answer (score 0):

`Posting` may be undefined as your $.post is running asynchronously. That's the first place I would look. Use it as a clue?

As far as solutions I can think of, have you tried:

```
$("#newsletter").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //serilize the form data
    var formData = $("#newsletter").serialize();
    var posting = $.post("<?= PROJECT_URL?>newsletter-response", formData).done(function(data){
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        if (response.done == 'yes') {
            $('#newsletter').fadeOut(500);
            response = "<h4>Thank you for registering.</h4>";
        } else {
            $('#newsletter').fadeOut(500);
            response = "<h4>Not successful</h4>";
        }
        $("#response").empty().append(response);
    });
 //..your logs removed
});
```

If so, perhaps a different pattern would work, using standard success callback?

```
$("#newsletter").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //serilize the form data
    var formData = $("#newsletter").serialize();
    var posting = $.post("<?= PROJECT_URL?>newsletter-response", formData, function(data){
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        if (response.done == 'yes') {
            $('#newsletter').fadeOut(500);
            response = "<h4>Thank you for registering.</h4>";
        } else {
            $('#newsletter').fadeOut(500);
            response = "<h4>Not successful</h4>";
        }
        $("#response").empty().append(response);
    })
);
});
```

..at which point the posting variable isn't needed anymore. You just $.post and chain up with those jQuery promises. On that point:

There are a bunch of ways to do this. Check out the docs for other ideas:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
Hope that helps!